# Toggle active class-angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have 2 links `EN` and `FR`(english and french languages)

```
<label  class = "lang" id="en"><a href=""  ng-click="c.changedLang('en');" ng-class=" eng ? active:'' ">EN </a>
                </label>
                <label>||
                </label>
                <label  class = "lang" id="fq"><a href=""  ng-click="c.changedLang('fq');" ng-class=" fren ? active:'' ">FR</a>
                </label>
```

When an `EN` link clicked active class should be added to english language,
when `FR` link clicked active class should be added to french language.

On page load active class added to english language.I am doing it based on `location.hash`.

client script

```
if(location.hash=='#en'){
                $scope.eng=true;
             $scope.fren=false;
            }
            else{
                $scope.fren=true;
                $scope.eng=false;
            }
```

CSS

```
.active{
color:#fff;
}
```

Is anything wrong in my code? active classes are not getting added properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your `ng-class` statements slightly wrong. `ng-class` expects an array or object as it's input. Change them to the following so that they get the expected input:

```
ng-class="{'active': eng}"
```

and

```
ng-class="{'active': fren}"
```

Here is a simple plunker to get you started: http://plnkr.co/edit/6l9C0lQISlTVxcIpumQI

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by updating the code like so:

HTML

```
<label class="lang" id="en">
    <a href="" ng-click="locale = 'en'" ng-class="{'active': locale == 'en'}">EN </a>
</label>
<label class="lang" id="fq">
    <a href="" ng-click="locale = 'fr'" ng-class="{'active': locale == 'fr'}">FR</a>
</label>
```

To set a default locale you can set the value of $scope.locale to either 'en' or 'fr'